# How to deploy OLAP Cube to local SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, olap-cube

I'm trying to deploy an OLAP cube to my local SQL Server in SQL Server Management Studio.

I have a local instance running in SQL Server Management Studio called:

```
MY_COMPUTER_NAME\instance
```

In Visual Studio 2019 I have created an OLAP cube.

Under Project -> Properties -> Deployment -> Target, I've set the server name of `<MY_COMPUTER_NAME>\instance` and named the database to `TestDatabaseDeploy`.

Then I build the project and try to deploy it. I get the following error:

> The project could not be deployed to the 'MY_COMPUTER_NAME\instance' server because of the following connectivity problems :
>
> A connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running.
>
> To verify or update the name of the target server, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, select Project Properties, click on the Deployment tab, and then enter the name of the server.

I have checked if the SQL Server browser is running and it is. I also changed the Log On properties to Local System Account. I also checked the SQL Server browser user privileges and are all set to modify, write, read...

To be honest I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Do you have the SSAS server installed?

Comment: Apparently, I forgot to check it during the installation. After I installed SSAS everything works fine. Tnx @Piotr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, SSAS server was not installed.